# adb : Cannot send commands to my device from the command line

Tags: android, galaxy

I'm trying to enable CheckJNI in order to debug my native code (see http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html).

I have a Galaxy S3 with the google USB drivers installed. I can install app and see my device when I use eclipse.

My problem is that I can't send any commands from cmd.exe to my device (it says "error : device not found"). I tried to send `adb shell setprop debug.checkjni 1` but I always got the same error.

I tried a different USB port, a different USB cable and I tried to start cmd.exe as an Administrator but I always got the same result. Anyone has had the same problem ? Any idea what I can do ?

Thanks

Comment: check available devices using adb devices first

Comment: Already did but no devices are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to send commands to 2 differents devices on 2 different computers with Windows 7, I finally installed a virtual machine with Ubuntu and there I could access my devices with command lines.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting ur device and computer also
then execute following commands:

```
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server
```

and then see if it show device using

```
  adb devices
```

for available device

then you can run commands in ur device using

```
    adb shell ......
```

Comment: Do you think it's related to the phone or to the OS (Windows 7 64 bits). I'm gonna try on another computer tomorrow (with Windows as well).

Comment: try [reinstalling] (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)  Android USB driver again?? if it works

Comment: Hmm I tried on another computer and I always get the same result, I don't know what wrong here... Thanks for the link, gonna try this, otherwise I'll need another phone to test if it's the phone

Comment: Ok I tried to reinstall the drivers and there I remembered that I had to install the Samsung USB driver to make my computer recognize my device. I tried to uninstall them and then tried to install the Google USB drivers but that didn't work -> [link](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34511/driver-issues-when-using-samsung-galaxy-siii-via-usb-for-development)

Comment: Yep, np that's not your fault, thanks for your answers anyway